# NDEigensystem with FEM: parasitic solutions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am trying to find the eigensystem of a system of 3 coupled ODEs. Analytically, the system spectrum should have a gap at [-2M,2M] (except for the degenerate state with E=0, strictly at the middle of the gap, which is of no interest). However, NDEigensystem with Finite Elements Method gives unwanted solutions inside the gap. Why is it so? How can I tune the procedure to get rid of the parasitic solutions? The MWE is below. Thank you!

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
M = 0.01;
B = 50;
A = 5;
R = 100;


{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[({
     {-2 B u''[x] - (2 B)/x u'[x] + (2 B/x^2 + 2 M) u[x] - 
       2 A ( v'[x] + 2/x v[x])},
     {A ( u'[x] - 1/x u[x]) - A ( z'[x] + 3/x z[x])},
     {2 A ( v'[x] - 2/x v[x]) + 
       2 B z''[x] + (2 B)/x z'[x] + (-18 B/x^2 - 2 M) z[x]}
    }), {u[x], v[x], z[x]}, {x, 0, R}, 1, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "BasisSize" -> 100, 
       "MaxIterations" -> 10000, "Shift" -> -M}}];

vals
{-0.00974081}
```

**upd:** I suspect the parasitic states arise because we are trying to solve the problem within a finite region, mesh being also of finite coarseness. If I take a finer mesh, the spatial region of $x \in (0,d)$ where parasitic solutions do exist shrinks, i.e. $d$ decreases, but never disappears completely. It is vital for me however to get rid of these solution in the spectrum.

**upd2.** I tried to use the graded mesh,

```
mesh = ToGradedMesh[{Line[{{0}, {R}}], <|"Alignment" -> "Left", 
     "MinimalDistance" -> 0.00001, "ElementCount" -> 1000|>}];
```

But the problem persists.

**upd3.** The numerical scheme is stabilized by detuning the band dispersion slightly, in addition to the graded mesh. This gives rise to the appearance of v''[x] in the second equation. The unwanted solutions in the gap (half of the gap in this case) disappear.

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper where this model analyzed with a statement about gap?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Here you are: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02041 The model is describing two-electron states in a system with two electron bands (conduction band and valence band). The MWE above is however hugely simplified, since there are no physical  interactions between electrons. Hence no states in the forbidden gap.

Comment: How about ToGradedMesh?

Comment: A few comments: Are you sure that `{u[x], v[x], z[x]}` is the right order? It matters.  What are the right-hand sides of your ODEs?  Do you really want  to use the default `NeumannValue` boundary conditions, especially since `v` enters only as first order in derivatives?  The ODEs are singular at `x = 0`.  The eigenfunction solution for `v` is very noisy.

Comment: @user21 I was waiting impatiently for your answer.) I tried to use the adaptive mesh, please see the update 2. But with no success.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The order is correct. The rhs of my equations is just the eigenvalue E multiplied by {u,v,z}, accordingly. This is an eigenvalue problem. I tried to use zero boundary conditions (of Dirichlet type), but this does not resolve the issue. The noisy solution for v is indeed the root of my troubles. Any non-zero solution for v should correspond exactly to zero eigenvalue E, right in the middle of the forbidden gap. But here the problematic solutions arise with eigenvalues all around the gap.

Comment: Which of the many sets of equations in the article you cited are you trying to solve?

Comment: @bbgodfrey This is a particular (simplified) case of Eq. (10).

Comment: I do not believe that `NDEigensystem` can solve these equations, because the second equation is not a second order ODE and because all three ODEs are singular at `x = 0`.  That said, the system is solvable by other means, but not easily.  Since `e = 0` is not of interest, first eliminate `v` algebraically and then determine the boundary conditions at `x = 0`, which definitely are not `NeumannValue`.  With that done, try the method at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691.

Comment: Unfortunately, I fail to see how equation relates to the equations you have given. Sorry, not sure I can help here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The second equation can become the second order if we detune the band dispersion slightly. Then the term (B1-B2)v''[x] appears. This solves the problem, as summarized in the update 3.

Comment: I am glad that you have solved your problem.  Please do look at the eigenfunctions, though, especially near `x = 0` to see that they are well-behaved.  You also should perform a series expansion of the ODEs at `x = 0`, which will uniquely determine the boundary conditions there.  For the ODEs in your questions, the lowest order nonzero terms are `u'[0]` and `z'''[0]`.

Comment: You could self answer you question. That would be a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The symmetric model considered in the post is numerically unstable. The numerical scheme is stabilized by, physically speaking, detuning the dispersion of two electron bands: $\pm M \pm B q^2 \to \pm M \pm B_i q^2$, $B_1 \ne B_2$. Which is by the way much more relevant to experiment. This leads to the appearance of the second derivative $(B_1-B_2)v''(x)$ in the second equation. This stabilizes the solution, so that the unwanted energy levels disappear from the gap. In an asymmetric model the solutions do arise in half of the gap (at $[0,2M]$ when $B_1>B_2$), but at $(-2M,0)$ there should be a gap in the spectrum. And there is!

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
M=0.01;
B1=120;
B2=20;
A=5;
R=100;
mesh=ToGradedMesh[{Line[{{0},{R}}],<|"Alignment"->"Left","MinimalDistance"->0.0001,"ElementCount"->1000|>}];


vals=NDEigenvalues[(-2B1 u''[x]-(2B1)/x u'[x]+(2 B1/x^2+2M) u[x]-2A( v'[x]+2/x v[x])
A( u'[x]-1/x u[x])+(B1-B2)(-v''[x]-1/x v'[x]+4/x^2 v[x])-A( z'[x]+3/x z[x])
2A( v'[x]-2/x v[x])+2B2 z''[x]+(2B2)/x z'[x]+(-18 B2/x^2-2M)z[x]

),{u[x],v[x],z[x]},Element[{x},mesh],16,Method->{"SpatialDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement"},"Eigensystem"->{"Arnoldi","BasisSize"->50,"MaxIterations"->5000,"Shift"->-M}}];

vals/(2M)
{2.14115, 12.7639, -13.7998, 20.1826, -27.6206, -41.9947, 42.36, \
53.9196, -59.5361, -80.7061, 83.2611, 104.974, -105.666, 132.798, \
-134.485, -167.198}
```